# Google Analitycs API get data with dimensions

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I work with Google Analitycs API. I want to get all sessions for last 7 days per day like this in only one API call:

**[day 1] -> 10**

**[day 2] -> 100
...**

I use this:

```
$service->data_ga->get('ga:'.$profile['id'],'7daysAgo','today','ga:sessions');
```

It works fine but return the sum. I've checked with https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ and for me needed i should add metrics **ga:date** so the date to be individualy per day not all.

I've tried to add metrics at the end of line:

```
$service->data_ga->get('ga:'.$profile['id'],'7daysAgo','today','ga:sessions','ga:date');
```

I got this error:

**Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message '(get) missing required param: 'start-date'' in**

Comment: Have you solved this problem ?

Comment: Yes. thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is this:

```
$SecondaryParams = array('dimensions' => 'ga:date');

$results = $service->data_ga->get('ga:'.$profile['id'],
                                  '7daysAgo',
                                  'today',
                                  'ga:sessions',   
                                   $SecondaryParams);
```

Send dimensions **as array.**